# Compiling MySQL 5.6 for Raspberry Pi - validation error

Tags: mysql, debian, raspberry-pi, gnupg, mysql-5.6

I am trying to compile MySQL 5.6 for install onto a Raspberry Pi (I need it for a geo module that wont work on 5.5, sigh...).

I am attempting it like so, at someone else's recommendation:

```
apt-get install build-essential debhelper devscripts debian-keyring
dget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mysql-5.6/mysql-5.6_5.6.19-1~exp1.dsc
cd mysql-5.6-5.6.19
dpkg-buildpackage -b
(install any missing build dependencies it compalins about)
dpkg-buildpackage -b
```

But, it errors on the second command:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ dget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mysql-5.6/mysql-5.6_5.6.19-1~exp1.dsc
dget: retrieving http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mysql-5.6/mysql-5.6_5.6.19-1~exp1.dsc
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2703  100  2703    0     0  16084      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 30715
dget: using existing mysql-5.6_5.6.19.orig.tar.gz
dget: using existing mysql-5.6_5.6.19-1~exp1.debian.tar.xz
mysql-5.6_5.6.19-1~exp1.dsc:
dscverify: mysql-5.6_5.6.19-1~exp1.dsc failed signature check:
gpg: keyblock resource `/home/pi/.gnupg/secring.gpg': file open error
gpg: Signature made Mon 21 Jul 2014 15:08:15 UTC using RSA key ID A0E7D8C3
gpg: fatal: /home/pi/.gnupg: directory does not exist!
secmem usage: 1408/1408 bytes in 2/2 blocks of pool 1408/32768
Validation FAILED!!
```

Anyone any idea why?

I did have to abort on the first attempt due to a power cut... I think during the first or second command was being executed... could this have screwed it up at all? Any way to rectify if so?

Comment: Check: [2.1.3.2 Signature Checking Using GnuPG](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/checking-gpg-signature.html).

Comment: I have gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.12... is that not good enough? It doesn't seem to want to update and the git clone fails because, allegedly, I don't have automake (system says I do have automake)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helps:

```
sudo gpg -k
```

Then install any missing packages that it errors on and then go for the final build/compile.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error, but my problem was that I wasn't running with elevated permissions. Once I ran the `dget` with `sudo` it worked.